# Newer versions of Wildfly not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I downloaded fresh Eclipse Neon3 for MacOS. I installed the latest version of JBOSS Tools that is 4.4.4.Final.

When I go to servers view and try to add the new server, under *JBossCommuniti* the maximum version of Wildfly I see is 11 and it even says *Wildfly 11 (Tech preview)*. And I want to use Wildfly 15.0.1. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's the latest JBoss Tools. https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.9.0.Final.html

Comment: ah, it seems that I accidentally downloaded and installed an older version of Eclipse which doesn't support the latest JBOSS Tools. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I accidentally downloaded an older version of Eclipse which didn't support the newest version of Jboss Tools.

Beware when downloading Eclipse to get the latest version. Sometimes google may display results to download some earlier versions as a first serch result, which was the problem in my case.

Under https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release  you see the list of all the releases. The newest shuold be at the top.